# Pandas: how to use value of a variable while making a new data frame using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and only have the company name "CC" , i want to get all company names for the group name it belongs i.e ( AA,BB,CC,DD and EE data frame)
condition : only company name are known rest of the data of columns gets change every week.

```
| S.no|Company| City         | Vendor | Group Number | Category  
| 1   |  AA   | Delhi        | Micro  | 9188-SC      | BBRNC011TR
| 2   |  BB   | Delhi        | Micro  | 9188-SC      | BBRNC011TR
| 3   |  CC   | Banglore     | Micro  | 9188-SC      | BBRNC011TR
| 4   |  DD   | Banglore     | Micro  | 9188-SC      | BBRNC011TR
| 5   |  EE   | Mumbai       | Micro  | 9188-SC      | BBRNC011TR
| 6   |  FF   | Colcutta     | Micro  | 8876-SC      | NCRNC011TR
| 7   |  GG   | Colcutta     | Micro  | 8876-SC      | NCRNC011TR
| 8   |  HH   | Noida        | Micro  | 8876-SC      | NCRNC011TR
| 9   |  II   | Noida        | Micro  | 8876-SC      | NCRNC011TR
```

I tried

```
dfG = df.loc['AA',['Group Number']]
dfA = dfG.loc['Group Number' == "9188-SC"]
```

it gave me the group number, I can find the next dataframe by this group number but the challenge is that it changes every day, so how can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the one-off cost of creating mappings from company to group and from group to companies is worthwhile. You can create two series for this purpose.

First map a given Company to GroupNumber. Then map GroupNumber to a list of companies. Here's a demo:

```
co_grp = df.drop_duplicates('Company').set_index('Company')['GroupNumber']
grp_cos = df.groupby('GroupNumber')['Company'].apply(list)

res = df[df['Company'].isin(grp_cos[co_grp['CC']])]

print(res)

   S.no Company      City Vendor GroupNumber    Category
0     1      AA     Delhi  Micro     9188-SC  BBRNC011TR
1     2      BB     Delhi  Micro     9188-SC  BBRNC011TR
2     3      CC  Banglore  Micro     9188-SC  BBRNC011TR
3     4      DD  Banglore  Micro     9188-SC  BBRNC011TR
4     5      EE    Mumbai  Micro     9188-SC  BBRNC011TR
```

Answer (score 0):

For your data, try something like this:

```
d.loc[d[" Vendor_Group_Number"].isin(d.loc[d['S.no']=="AA"][" Vendor_Group_Number"].tolist())]
```

Comment: hello my dataframe has following column  S.no | Company |City | Vendor | Group Number | Category  , i dont know but somehow it changed a little , but i dont have "Vendor_Group_Number" here. New to python and this plateform. "AA" is the company name here